# Metronome/tempo markings

Tags: tempo, meter

[image]What does the following equation mean, as shown in the second to last line?  What significance does this have in music? I have also seen this for different values as well.

---

[image: 16th note = 16th note]

Comment: The magified version seems to mismatch the top left of the big picture where an eighth and a sixteenth are on the sides of the equals-sign,

Comment: @guidot - the magnified image is from halfway across the second last line

Comment: That magnified image was taken from the 2/4 bar below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eighth note equals eighth note piano notation](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/58966/eighth-note-equals-eighth-note-piano-notation)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These *metric equations* sometimes accompany a time signature change.  They indicate whether or not the note values (symbols) are to change duration.

When the symbols on either side of the metric equation are different, it usually means that the beat value (changing between un-dotted and dotted) is to remains the same duration, but the subdivisions of a beat has changed (between simple and compound).

In your case (the symbols on either side are the same) the note values should remain constant across the change in time signature, while the note value of a beat presumable does change.